# Developing a game with complex (and undefined) rules?

Tags: java, python, rules

How would you develop a game that could end up with complex rules but you need to work on the rules (add, tweak, balance) a lot? I have looked at rule-based languages but I haven't found quite useful enough information regarding this.

UI etc. will be developed later, first I'd need to iteratively develop the rules and formulas and test them out between iterations. The game in question would be a tactical two-player game where players select "troops" and a large part of the game is choosing the correct troop setup. So the rules could be something like

```
If attacker's skill A is greater than defenders skill B and defender does not have extra skill Z then ...
```

That's obviously a very simple rule, I expect there to be dozens, if not hundreds of rules, with paths (if A then if B....).

For testing I would write a test framework that can run the rule sets through with large number of iterations and logging that allows me to see how the latest changes affected balance. It would also be useful to be able to define acceptable values and a possibility to see easily the changes. What tools are there for this?

The language of choice is either Python or Java (depending on whether I want to target Android or not - probably I will).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with [larsmans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299445/developing-a-game-with-complex-and-undefined-rules/5299546#5299546) I'm going to suggest that you use [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) for your rules development.  It's just the best language in semi-common use for doing exactly the kind of thing you want to do.  I will, however, instead recommand [tuProlog](http://alice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/) as looking like the ideal environment for your needs given that you want to write the game in Java.  TuProlog is intended as an embeddable Prolog environment (can be embedded in Java or in .NET) with very finely-tuned library inclusion so you don't have to carry around a whole, bloated Prolog world with you when you're using just small parts of it.

Here's the blurb from the web site:

> tuProlog is a light-weight Prolog system for distributed applications and infrastructures, intentionally designed around a minimal core (containing only the most essential properties of a Prolog engine), to be later configured by (statically and dynamically) loading/unloading libraries of predicates. tuProlog also natively supports multi-paradigm programming, providing a clean, seamless integration model between Prolog and mainstream object-oriented languages -- namely Java, for tuProlog Java version, and any .NET-based language (C#, F#..), for tuProlog .NET version. It is also easily deployable, just requiring the presence of a Java/CLR virtual machine and an invocation upon a single self-contained archive file. Interoperability is further developed along the two main lines of Internet standard patterns and coordination models.

Comment: I will look into this first because after a very quick look at all the suggestions it looks like this holds the most promise. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you'll do, in this sort of program you'll end up implementing half of [Prolog](http://learnprolognow.org/) anyway. Check out the [forward-chaining](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Forward_chaining), [backward-chaining](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Backward_chaining), and [backtracking](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Backtracking) algorithms.

A pure-Java version of Prolog called [Jekejeke](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/10_pro08/package.html) was recently released. I can't comment on its quality.

Python makes it much easier than Java to implement backtracking using generators and `yield` statements.

Comment: Ahh... you beat me to suggesting PROLOG. It's particularly awesome for a project like this because it does all the backtracking and forward chaining by default, whereas in any other language, you'd end up having to implement all of that from scratch

Comment: I agree it sounds like a job for Prolog, at a first glance, but in his case it might be an overkill. As a rule of the thumb, a game designer should not let the rules become *too* complex. If the rules are very complex, the game designer has two unpleasant choices: explain them all to the players somehow and risk alienating them because of the complexity; or keep them under the wraps and risk alienating players because there are border cases where they don't understand what the heck just happened.

Comment: @Vojislav: alternatively, find a community that *thrives* on interpreting complex rules ;-) See Magic The Gathering ('though they *try* to make the intuitive interpretation of the rules the correct one).

Comment: @Joachim: There's always that, but it's a bit of a niche ;) A rather successful niche, in case of Magic The Gathering. For games like that, complicating the rules is actually their business model :P

Comment: Well, I'll have at least a look since learning at least the principles of new programming languages is always interesting. And thanks for the techniques as well, they sound interesting.

Comment: @Vojislav: Good points, I prefer a rule-set which you play instinctively rather than by counting. But of course it has to feel fair and logical. Not easy, I know, but that's the sort of games I usually enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question, though a bit broad and generic. I'll try to answer it according to my interpretation of what you're asking ;)

Your main concern seems to be about being able to express the rules in a concise, readable way that would allow you to always keep the definition clear and change it rapidly. Since you say the rules are probably going to get complex, I believe your best bet would be to write a DSL for them.

Try to writing a grammar that would be sufficient for describing your rules and then see how to plug it into your game. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) could be very helpful there, especially because it supports both Java and Python.

Comment: I need to have a look at ANTRL at some point as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try [The A.I. of F.E.A.R.](http://web.media.mit.edu/~jorkin/gdc2006_orkin_jeff_fear.pdf). there FSM (finite state machine) was combined with A* pathfinding. instead of finding a path in a terrain the engine found chains of goals to implement generation of "intelligent" behaviour of agents on the fly. maybe there is something inspiring in there for you.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to the question (unless you'd want to implement an AI that *exploits* those rules for its own gain). I have to add that the paper is quite interesting, 'though ;-)